# How to save correct date time with timezone when using jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timezone

I'm using Java and JDBC connect to a PostgreSQL database. I have a problem saving time to the database. My database have table student with column look like

```
Id,Name,Created_at(timestamp)

//some row here
```

I using JDBC connect to PostgreSQL and save my data

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/someDatabase?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

When I insert data my data looks like

```
Student student = new Student()
student.name = "some name";
student.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now()
```

//some logic save

However, when I insert into the database, PostgreSQL saves the same time  as my server. I want if my time server is "2021-10-10 00:00:00", when I save to database it must save to database as
"2021-10-09 15:00:00". I want when it save it must convert to timezone Japan.

When I select database, timezone on PostgreSQL +9 . If I change code some like:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

it does not help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong classes and types.

Never use `TimeZone` and `Timestamp` classes. These are part of the terrible date-time classes from the earliest versions of Java, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specially replaced by `ZoneId` and `Instant`/`OffsetDateTime`.

In Postgres, be sure your `created_at` column is of the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, not `WITHOUT`.

Generally best to capture the current moment as a `Instant`. That class represents a moment as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Unfortunately, the people writing the JDBC 4.2 spec inexplicably required support for `OffsetDateTime` but not the two more commonly used classes `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. No matter, we can easily convert back and forth, if your particular JDBC driver does not support `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or, skip the `Instant`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Send to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

The `LocalDateTime` class is the wrong one here. That class represents a date and time without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So that class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline. So this class cannot be used to record when something happened. I cannot think of any scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` would be the right thing to do.

These topics have been addressed on many existing Questions and Answers. Search to learn more.

Comment: There is nothing inexplicable about requiring support for `OffsetDateTime` and not `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`: the SQL standard only defines support for offset-based `WITH TIME ZONE` types, and therefor so does JDBC. Using `Instant` wouldn't preserve any stored offset information, and for storing wouldn't be much different from using an `OffsetDateTime` with offset zero.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Converting back-and-forth between `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` is utterly simple. Why not require JDBC drivers to perform that conversion for the convenience of the calling programmer? Regarding `ZonedDateTime`, thank you for the explanation, that makes sense now.

Comment: Because an Instant is not an OffsetDateTime, and the choice was made to only use the type that directly maps to the equivalent SQL standard type.